# Extending a crossfilter/d3 example to handle wrapping bar charts

Tags: d3.js, crossfilter

I am in the process of trying to extend Jason Davies' example of crossfilterjs example (you can see it here at http://square.github.io/crossfilter/) to make it able to hand larger data sets. My idea was to make the bar charts wrap.

This is what I have so far: http://bl.ocks.org/elsherbini/5564315

I am trying to figure out how I could make the axis and brush wrap as well. If you open that example in a full window, you can see that right now it just draws the axis at the bottom, and the brush goes over the whole thing. My goal is to make the brush and axis wrap as well, but I'm not sure how to proceed.

Does anyone have experience trying to extend d3.svg.axis() or d3.svg.brush()? Do I need to extend those at all, or is there some other workaround?